# Lazy list s-expression matrix in smalltalk

Tags: matrix, block, smalltalk, lazy-sequences, s-expression

So I have a class to create in smalltalk called LazyMatrix. The class only has 1 instance variable and cannot be a subclass of anything but Object. The instance variable of LazyMatrix is called block and must be a back. I initialize LazyMatrix like this:

```
initialize
block:=[nil]
```

There will be a method for setting values

```
setRow:column:value:
```

This method will redefine the block by setting the new block as [#(i j value).[nil]]. Each subsequent call adds an array of 3 to the block, so it expands like [#(i j value).[#(i j value).[nil]]] much like an s-expression or "lazy list".

So I need to access the head of this block (i.e. [#(i j value) ) as well as the tail of this bock (i.e. [#(i j value).[nil]] ). How do I do this in smalltalk? I know calling value on the block will return the tail... now I need to return the head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an array to your block doesn't get you anywhere. Think in terms of *behavior*, not about *data structures*.

I guess your teacher did provide you with the overall idea: given a row and column, answer the  associated value; otherwise ask the "tail" for the answer.

That is *literally* how you would implement it in Smalltalk using a block closure (where the "tail" is the previously set block). Inside the block, put code that does the testing and answering and tail recursion. Do not make a data structure, tail and head are just metaphors to reason about this style of coding.

I just implemented your LazyMatrix in Squeak, it is just a few lines of code. Cute example, indeed. And no arrays or collections involved, at all.

**Hint:** The key to this puzzle is realizing that every call to setRow:column:value: can create a new block, which is independent of all the previously created blocks.

Comment: So I am initializing it like 'block:= [ :i :j| 0 ]'. Then 'setRow:column:value:
    | arr tail head |
 arr:= Array new:3.
 arr at:1 put:i. arr at:2 put:j. arr at:3 put:val .
 tail:=block.
 head:= [ :r :c |  arr.
  ( (r=(arr at:1)) and: (c=(arr at:2)) )
  ifTrue: [ (arr at:3) ] 
  ifFalse: [ tail ]
   ].
 block:=head.'

Is this a good way to do it? You mentioned not using arrays at all... How would I do something like that? Thank you for the help.

Comment: The initialization is correct. If you would ask that first block for any row or column it will answer zero. Now, imagine you had just a single other block, that would answer e.g. 42 if the row was 3 and the column 5. For any other row or column it would evaluate the first block instead. That is very easy to write down, and will emulate a matrix of all zeros and a single 42 in one place. Now if you make a third block that answers e.g. 69 if the row is 5 and the column is 3, otherwise it evaluates the second block, you will have a matrix with 2 non-zero values. See? No arrays involved.

Comment: Ok, I wrote it up like that and everything seems to work. Just one more question... If I wanted to write methods that would add/multiply all the values stored in the matrix by some scalar s, what would be the best way to do this? Should I use some form of inject: ? Thanks.

Comment: There is no list, so inject could not possibly work. Again, this assignment (as I understand it) is purely about behavior, not data structures. So ask yourself, what is the desired behavior? That is, if you think of the object as a black box, what would it answer after a series of inputs, not worrying about how it is all stored? (Hint: read up on functional programming, which is what we're doing here, just using an object-oriented language. This is not how you would normally implement a lazy matrix in Smalltalk, but it is a good learning exercise.)

Comment: One more hint: if you set a row/column to a certain value, and then to a different value, it works fine. The value set last will be answered.  Now think about the "stored value". How was it changed?

Comment: A correction to the comment about using some form of inject.

Comment: The reason not to use some form of inject is that inject is a reducer, whereas to add or multiply by a scalar you would need a transformer--i.e. some form of #collect.   The difficulty in doing this is that there appears to be no list--just a device that can answer the values most recently stored at specific locations, but nothing else--e.g. it hasn't the properties of a rectangular coordinate system. This is an illusion.  There actually is a list, it just cannot yet be traversed for general purposes. Needs a way to #do: something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go in two ways here. The first one (which I wouldn't recommend) is to model your s-expressions as lists in lambda calculus. You basically use blocks as functions and you are done. [Here](http://safalra.com/science/lambda-calculus/tuples-and-lists/) you can fond an explanation of writing lists using lambda calculus. As an example, in Smalltalk you would write

```
empty = λfx.x
```

as

```
empty := [:f :x | x].
```

Now, going that road would be basically writing a functional program in an OO language, which I wouldn't do. If you want to use the symbolic approach for lists then you should model it with objects. Have a `EmptyList` class and a `Cons` class (`Cons` would have an `element` and a `list` inst var), so that you create a list by doing:

```
listWithOne := Cons element: 1 list: EmptyList new.
```

The `head` and `tail` methods can be trivially written in the `Cons` class by just returning the inst var values. You can also define `head` and `tail` methods in the `EmptyList` class, so that now `EmptyList` and `Cons` are polymorphic.

***Added***: Ok, just for fun, an implementation that uses blocks and arrays, functional style:

```
| empty cons head tail test |
empty := [nil].
cons := [:i :j :value :old | [Array with:i with:j with:value with:old]].
head := [:list | list value ifNotNil: [:v | v copyFrom:1 to:3]].
tail := [:list | list value at: 4].

test := cons value: 1 value: 1 value: 'Hi' value: (cons value: 1 value: 2 value: 'Ho' value: empty).
"Print each one"
head value: test.
head value: (tail value: test).
head value: (tail value: (tail value: test)).
```

HTH

Comment: I don't think this is helpful. There is no need to actually emulate a list data structure (see my answer).